# Objective-C Fast enumeration access instance vars

Tags: objective-c, variables, enumeration

Suppose I have 4 UITextFields (line1, line2, line3 and line4) as ivars in My viewcontroller class. I want to fast enumerate an array that consists of 4 strings and then populate each of the UITextFields with the string data from the array. How would I get a reference to each of the UITextFields? I know one way is possible with KVC (see code) but is there an other option to achieve this?

```
int i = 1;
for(NSString *string in array) {
    NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"line%@", i];
    UITextField *field = [self valueForKey:fieldName];
    field.text = string;
}
```

Comment: *cough* you probably want to increment that `i` and it's not a `%@`. I'll post more helpful comments as an actual answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the `UITextfield`'s in an array and do

```
UITextField *textField = nil;

[stringArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    textField = [textFieldArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    textField.text = obj;         
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the tag attribute on each UITextField and then use the - (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag method.

Comment: Assuming it works visually, a smart move could be to collect all the text fields into a common parent view that has no other subviews. That would effectively give them a unique namespace for their tags, to an extent.

Comment: I've done things where I've just set the tags to something unique like 1001, 1002, ... Then handle the modification, subtract 1000 in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to *add your text fields to an array*.  Now that you've got a reference to all of them, you can set all of their values to whatever you want:

```
//Thanks @Tommy for the array suggestion
NSArray *arrayOfFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4, nil];
for(NSString *string in array)
   [fields setValue:string  forKey:@"text"]; //<---Thanks @Paul.s

[fields release];
```

Comment: Or even just `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4, nil];` for compactness.

Comment: That would set them all to the same value. The OP has an array of strings. But even easier still with your example you could do: `[fields setValue:@"foo" forKey:@"text"];`. The `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` method always looks a bit nasty to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're willing to have iOS 4 be the floor of your support, you can now build collections directly in the interface designer. So you'd declare something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UITextField)
            NSArray *textFieldCollection;
```

You can then wire that up to as many `UITextField`s as you like and the `NSArray` will be created and populated for you by the normal NIB loading mechanisms.

Comment: This is only for interface builder right? I prefer to keep my hands away from IB :P

Comment: Interface Builder or the equivalent built-in functionality of Xcode 4, yes. If you're creating your views programmatically, it feels odd that you're keeping your references in individually named instance variables at all. Why not just put them in an array?